# Java: How to access image outside of project file?

Tags: java

I am making a program where the user chooses an image file on their computer and it displays it in a window. I have the line of code
`image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream(path));`
where path is the absolute path to the image. The error it returns is
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!`
What am I doing wrong or is it not possible to get an Image outside of the project file?

Comment: Are you sure that's the line the error is originating from? The error message would seem to indicate the existence of an `input` variable, which your snippet doesn't have

Comment: I think the method you want to use is `https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read(java.net.URL)` - you should not wrap your URL in `getResourceAsStream`

Comment: @ScaryWombat I changed the URL to the path because it's a file path, not a web URL sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Branickin you should not use `getClass().getResourceAsStream()` when you have absolute path check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, `getClass().getResourceAsStream()` reads the image from default class path(either in the folder of your classes or the contents of the jar file)!

So you would want :

```
BufferedImage img = null;
try {
    img = ImageIO.read(new File(path));
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```